# Wordpress Post via e-mail writes a random string for the post body

Tags: posts, email

This is my first time using Post via e-mail on Wordpress. I set up the e-mail with googleapps/gmail such that the e-mail server is `ssl://pop.gmail.com:995` with the associated username and password.

Wordpress successfully retrieves the e-mail but when it writes to a post, only the title of the e-mail is displayed. The body of the post includes a random string.

For example, I sent an e-mail:

```
Subject: Test post by e-mail
Body: Sphinx of black quartz, judge my vow!
```

The post on my blog, however shows the following:

```
Title: Test post by e-mail
Body: U3BoaW54IG9mIGJsYWNrIHF1YXJ0eiwganVkZ2UgbXkgdm93IQ==
```

How can I fix this such that the body of the post correctly shows the body of the e-mail sent?

Answer (score 1):

You should send email using plain text format.
See [official documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_to_your_blog_using_email#Blog_By_Email_From_Yahoo.21_Mail.2C_Gmail_and_Hotmail) for further info.